# Ansible copy large file in async mode

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

When trying to upload a file with a size of 1GB to a remote server, It shows following error:

> "async is not supported for this task."

Here I'am using async with copy module

Here is my ansible playbook

```
- hosts: myhost
  tasks: 
    - name: 'copy large file'
      copy:
        src: "large_file"
        dest: "/home/user"
      async: 
      poll: 0
      register: copy_sleeper

    - name: 'check on async task'
      async_status:
        jid: "{{ copy_sleeper.ansible_job_id }}"
      register: job_result
      until: job_result.finished
      retries: 5
```

Is there any solutions in this case?

Comment: As a solution, I recommend to use `synchronize` or at least `command: rsync`.

Comment: Hi, I tried with synchronize but it couldn't check on task status.
It shows this error
`'dict object' has no attribute 'ansible_job_id'`

Answer (score 2):

I resolved this by using `scp` command as follows:

```
- name: Copy large file in async
  command: "scp -P {{ssh_port}} path/to/src {{ ssh_user }}@{{ target_host }}:/path/to/dest"
  async: 3600
  poll: 0
  register: copy_sleeper

- name: 'Check if async task has finished'
  async_status:
    jid: "{{ copy_sleeper.ansible_job_id }}"
  register: job_result
  until: job_result.finished
  retries: 3600
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that scp and rsync were extremely similar in moving a large 5GB iso to the remote system.  I timed them both at around the 110 - 115 second mark.

I ended up using the following script which also avoids some permissions issues common to rsync

```
- name: async_win_vm_files_migration
  # using ansible user and key from the control system to push rsync copy
  command: > 
    rsync -aAXvP --no-g --omit-dir-times --no-perms -e "ssh -p 925 -i /home/ansible/.ssh/id_ed25519" 
    --keep-dirlinks 
    --exclude={"/dev/*","/proc/*","/sys/*","/tmp/*","/run/*","/mnt/*","/.git/*","/.pyc/*","/.svn/*","/.gvfs/*","/.cache/*","/lost+found"} 
    "{{ files_path }}/async_large_files/windows_vms/" ansible@{{ host_ansible_ip }}:/SM/data-drive/sm_virt_machines/
  delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
  become: yes # become root
  # how many seconds ansible should wait between checking to see if done
  # if you know your entire playbook is going to take 2 minutes, you may as well make this close to that. 
  # there is no 'too small' number but if you put in more seconds than the entire playbook runs, this will spawn an error
  async: 600 # 5 minutes
  register: sm_async_win_vm_files
```