# Deploy large size OVF to ESXI with Ansible

Tags: automation, ansible

I want to deploy a large size OVF to an ESXI with Ansible.

This is the playbook:

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks: 
   - community.vmware.vmware_deploy_ovf:
      hostname: "192.168.15.1"
      username: "root"
      password: "P@55w0rd"
      datastore: "datastore1"
      name: "NewVM"
      power_on: no
      ovf: /home/user/ubuntu-16.04-amd64.ovf
    delegate_to: localhost
```

The process is interrupted during deploying OVF with:

> "msg": "<urlopen error The write operation timed out>"

I think this is because the OVF file is big. (2.3 GB). How do I automate this task?

Comment: You actually already automated it! Perhaps take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61247462/ansible-copy-large-file-in-async-mode